# Do you think I am using the Array.IndexOf method wrong?

Tags: c#, .net

**Here is my Main method.**

```
public class Program
{   
    static void Main()
    {
        Solution slt = new Solution();
        int[] nums = { 3,2,3 };
    }
}
```

**Here is my TwoSum method**

```
public class Solution
{
    public int[] TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
           for(int j = i+1; j < nums.Length; j++)
            {
                if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
                {
                    int[] Index = new int[2];
                    var firstIndex = Array.IndexOf(nums,nums[i]);
                    var secondIndex = Array.IndexOf(nums,nums[j]);
                    Index[0] = firstIndex;
                    Index[1] = secondIndex;
                    return Index;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("No two sum found");
    }
}
```

*What I want to do is throw the index numbers into an array and return them. SecondIndex should be 2 but it returns 0. Is it because I am using the Array.IndexOf method incorrectly?*

Comment: I don't know why you are doing the things you do.... Look at `num[i]`. What does that mean? It means "_give me the int at the index given by **i**_". So, you get the number at index `i`.
Then you do `Array.IndexOf(nums,nums[i])` which translates to "_Give me the index of the number whose index i already know, because it is the value of `i`_". The same applies to `num[j]` as well...

Comment: As for secondIndex being 0: Note that Array.IndexOf finds the **first occurence** (leftmost occurence, if you will) of a number in an array. So, if your array is for example `[3, 2, 3]` and `j = 2`, then `Array.IndexOf(nums,nums[j])` will return 0, obviously. Because the value of `num[2]` is 3, and the first time the number 3 appears in the array is at index 0, so Array.IndexOf would return 0 in this example. Pay attention to the documentation for Array.IndexOf: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0

Comment: I haven't the faintest idea what this code is supposed to do. Any case, maybe see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. At a guess, is this the LeetCode Two Sum problem? If so it looks like you can just do `if(nums[i] + nums[j] == target) return new [] {i, j};`

Comment: I think you might actually want `var firstIndex = i;` and `var secondIndex = j;`

Answer (score 1):

*"Do you think I am using the Array.IndexOf method wrong?"*

Yes, I do. Because you use this method without reason. You say...

- I have an index(i and j), give me the value, then
- I have a value, give me the index

But your expectation that [`Array.IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0#system-array-indexof-1(-0()-0-system-int32)) returns the current index(which it doesn't know) is also wrong. It doesn't return 2 if you search for 3 which is at index 0 and 2, but it returns...

> the zero-based index of the **first occurrence** of value

Since 3 is at index 0 and 2 it returns 0.

As said, you don't need it at all since you know already the index:

```
int[] Index = new int[2];                        
Index[0] = i;
Index[1] = j;
return Index;
```

Sidenote: I'd prefer something more readable like a named tuple or real class:

```
public (int FirstIndex, int SecondIndex) TwoSum(int[] nums, int target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.Length; j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                return (i, j);
            }
        }
    }

    return (-1, -1);
}
```